# How does the React class constructor method view properties being bound that haven't been defined yet?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, binding

When a method is being bound in the React class constructor, how does it view the value of the property being bound, if the constructor is the first thing to run, then when the handleClick property is being bound to the component instance below, how does it know what the value of handleClick will be as it's not defined until after the constructor.

So I'm wondering if the constructor runs first, is it even aware that a method called handleClick has been defined and if so how because it's defined after the constructor?

```
class Toggle extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {isToggleOn: true};
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleClick() {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      isToggleOn: !prevState.isToggleOn
    }));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <button onClick={this.handleClick}>
        {this.state.isToggleOn ? 'ON' : 'OFF'}
      </button>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Just like in regular JS, it probably scans all your code before it even starts executing. Have you ever heard of hoisting in JavaScript? Let's say you define a bunch of functions at the bottom of a file, and then want to use them at the top of your file, JS already knows about the functions, because it scanned your code and hoisted them to be already in scope. Calling those functions at the top of the file will work just fine. I'd venture to say the constructor does not run at all until the class knows about all the other methods.

Comment: I did think that could be an option but just wondered if someone knew the definite answer.

Answer (score 0):

It is called hoisting https://stackabuse.com/hoisting-in-javascript.
You can find a bunch of examples in the article that I attached.

Comment: sorry to correct you, but there is no such a thing as hoisting, hoisting is the misunderstood of how really the runtime engine works.
start by watching this video
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HcW5-P2SNec&t=100s

Comment: That link makes no mention of class methods being hoisted.

Answer (score 0):

what do you mean they would be undefined? when you define a class and implement its methods the class "knows" what attributes and properties it has.

there is something call context execution, for this purpose let's say that it is `this` in other words, it is the object running in the current scope.

if you have a component like this one.

```
class Button extend Component {

  constructor (props) {
     super(props);
  }

  handler () {
//    ...
  }

  render () {
     return (
        <button onClick={this.handler} >Click</button>
     )
  }
}
```

that creates a button. When user clicks the button it executes the method `handler`, now let me ask you what is `this` who is executing `handler`.

the user?
the button?
the window?

the onClick is an event listener, it is a reaction triggered by each time the user interacts with the window. so who calls the onClick function is was not the button, but the window. the handler method of the button is none but a wrapper of the original function so the conext is under window thats why when you refer to other stuff of the class button everything is undefined because you are looking for those things in the window object.

`this.handler = this.handler.bind(this);`

it only specifies who is going to be `this`, but do not believe me I am just a mortal.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind

what to learn more watch this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bv_5Zv5c-Ts

Comment: Thanks, I understand the context and why we bind. I'm just wondering if the constructor is the very first thing that runs, does it know about the other methods in the class so that it can bind them and if so how? because I thought the interpreter would reach those methods after the constructor has run, so it wouldn't know about them.

Comment: short answer yes, it knows about it. JavaScript is a just in time compilation language. before your code executes the run time engine reads yow code in the current scope and depending on how you declared your class the run time engine might be able to know its methods or not. this books can tell you alot more https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/1st-ed/README.md

Comment: Thanks, I'm assuming it does it because of some compiler logic as well before running the code.

Answer (score -1):

It is because of the hoisting, actually it is the specialty of the constructor in the class, you can clear your doubt by understanding the constructor.
visit here for easy explanation - 'https://ponyfoo.com/articles/binding-methods-to-class-instance-objects'

Comment: That link is kind of generic about binding, it doesn't explain why you can bind methods that are defined later.